# React does not render recursive reactive components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Given this component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';

export default class SubscriptionView extends TrackerReact(Component) {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    let params = props.params || [];

    if (!Array.isArray(params)) {
      params = [params];
    }

    this.state = {
      subscription: {
        collection: Meteor.subscribe(props.subscription, ...params)
      }
    };
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.subscription.collection.stop();
  }


  render() {
    let loaded = this.state.subscription.collection.ready();

    if (!loaded) {
      return (
        <section className="subscription-view">
          <h3>Loading...</h3>
        </section>
      );
    }

    return (
      <section className="subscription-view">
        { this.props.children }
      </section>
    );
  }
};
```

And another component :

```
import SubscriptionView from './SubscriptionView.jsx';

export const Foo = () => (
  <SubscriptionView subscription="allFoo">
    <SubscriptionView subscription="singleBar" params={ 123 }>
      <div>Rendered!</div>
    </SubscriptionView>
  </SubscriptionView>
);
```

The first `Subscription` is re-rendered when the data is available, however the second one is rendered only once and nothing more. If I place a `console.log(this.props.subscription, ready);` inside the render function of `SubscriptionView`, I see

```
allFoo false
allFoo true
singleBar false
```

and that's it.

On the server side, both publish methods are

```
Meteor.publish('allFoo', function () {
  console.log("Subscribing foos");
  return Foos.find();
});

Meteor.publish('singleBar', function (id) {
  console.log("Subscribing bar", id);
  return Bars.find({ _id: id });
});
```

Both of the publish methods are being called.

Why isn't the second `SubscriptionView` reactive?

---

#### *** Solution ***

This is based on [alexi2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928525/react-does-not-render-recursive-reactive-components/38928560?noredirect=1#comment65214011_38928560)'s comment :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';

export default class SubscriptionLoader extends TrackerReact(Component) {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    let params = props.params || [];

    if (!Array.isArray(params)) {
      params = [params];
    }

    this.state = {
      done: false,
      subscription: {
        collection: Meteor.subscribe(props.subscription, ...params)
      }
    };
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.subscription.collection.stop();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (!this.state.done) {
      this.setState({ done: true });

      this.props.onReady && this.props.onReady();
    }
  }


  render() {
    let loaded = this.state.subscription.collection.ready();

    if (!loaded) {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      );
    }

    return null;
  }
};
```

Then, inside the parent component's `render` method :

```
<section className="inventory-item-view">
  <SubscriptionLoader subscription='singleBar' params={ this.props.id } onReady={ this.setReady.bind(this, 'barReady') } />
  <SubscriptionLoader subscription='allFoos' onReady={ this.setReady.bind(this, 'foosReady') } />
  { content }
</section>
```

Where `setReady` merely sets the component's state, and `content` has a value only if `this.state.barReady && this.state.foosReady` is true.

It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try separating out your `SubscriptionView` Components like this:

```
import SubscriptionView from './SubscriptionView.jsx';

export const Foo = () => (
    <div>
      <SubscriptionView subscription="singleBar" params={ 123 }>
        <div>Rendered!</div>
      </SubscriptionView>
      <SubscriptionView subscription="allFoo">
        <div>Rendered Again!</div>
      </SubscriptionView>
    </div>
);
```

**Edit from comments conversation**

Not sure if I am on the right track but you could build Foo as a 'smart' component that passes props to each SubscriptionView as required, and then use Foo as a reusable component.

> Let's say that what I need to render is FooBarForm, which requires both Foos and Bars to be registered, in that specific use case. How would you do that?

You could create Components `Foos` and `Bars` that took props as required and create a parent component `FooBarForm` that contained those Components and passed the necessary data.

`FooBarForm` would handle the state and as that changed pass it to the props of its child components.

Now state is being centrally managed by the parent component, and the child components render using props passed from the parent.

The child components would re-render as their props changed depending on whether the state being passed from the parent component had changed.

Comment: The example is trivial, however the real application requires too collections to be available. I just thought I'd write a general purpose component for that, then reuse it. By the time the children (ex: a form) is actually rendered, all collections would be ready and all data would be available. Since the app will have many of these requirements, sometimes one, two or three subscriptions, I hoped to make the most of the reusable nature of React.

Comment: Not sure if I am on the right track but you could build Foo as a 'smart' component that passes props to each SubscriptionView as required, and then use Foo as a reusable component.

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting... Let's say that what I need to render is `FooBarForm`, which requires both `Foos` and `Bars` to be registered, in that specific use case. How would you do that?

Comment: You could create Components Foos and Bars that took props as required and create a parent component FooBarForm that contained those Components and passed the necessary data.

Comment: FooBarForm would handle the state and as that changed pass it to the props of its child components. Now state is being centrally managed by the parent component, and the child component render props. The child components would re-render as their props changed depending on whether the state being passed from the parent component had changed.

Comment: Wait, I think I get what you mean... I'm attempting a refactor and will post if I'm successful.

Comment: Cool, I'll keep an eye on this post.

Comment: I'd update this if I were you, quoting your own comment in the answer. Cheers!